# jQuery toggleClass Isn't Working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm working on a website that has a button that shows a menu when clicked. I'm trying to get it to change colour when active, but the toggleClass isn't changing the background colour when the button is clicked. Here is the code I'm using.

```js
$(".services-btn").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("active-btn");
});
```

```css
div.services-btn {
  background-color: black;
  color: #f9f9f9;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 15px 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 80px;
}
.active-btn {
  background-color: darkred;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="services-btn mobile">Services</div>
```

Comment: Is `active-btn` the class? The CSS has a rule for `.active-btn`.

Comment: because your toggle a class which has no style.. it should be `active-btn` not `active`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your CSS to this

```
div.services-btn {
    background-color: black;
    color: #f9f9f9;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 15px 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 80px;
}

div.services-btn.active {
    background-color: darkred;
}
```

It because in your jQuery your add `.active` class, not `.active-btn` as you type on your code on CSS. You can also change your jQuery add class into `.active-btn` and don't change your CSS and it works properly too.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to change that when I was typing the question. It is currently set to `$(this).toggleClass("active-btn");`, but still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you put a fiddle?

Comment: I'm not sure how to share it, but it's under the title "jQuery toggleClass StackOverflow"

Comment: Following both your advice and Jalon's, I managed to fix it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Put active on your .service-btn class and do the styling for your active class using css.

```
.services-btn {
    background-color: black;
    color: #f9f9f9;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 15px 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 80px;
}

.services-btn.active {
    background-color: darkred;
}
```

Your jquery is worng. `$(this.toggleClass("active-btn")` should be a menu or something else you want to toggle.